# How to work with SDL_surface pixel data?

Tags: c, sdl, pixel, surface

I need to read bmp image file, increase the brightness, and then save the bmp. I decided to use SDL2, because it seemed to the easiest for me to load bmp-s. I wrote a code, but I do not understand how to work with SDL_surface pixels. It is just a pointer to the actual pixel data. How can I increase values, and then save the modified bmp? Here is my try:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
SDL_Surface* picture = NULL;
Uint8 red, green, blue;

picture = SDL_LoadBMP("avxsample.bmp");
if (picture != NULL)
{
    printf("BMP File is loaded!\n");

    // This part is unclear for me...

    SDL_SaveBMP(picture, "avxsamlpe_new.bmp");
}
else
{
    printf("Cannot load BMP File!\n");
    SDL_FreeSurface(picture);
}

return 0;
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: The code above just loads the BMP file...do you have any code where you attempted to work with the pixels?  Otherwise we may have to point you at a pointer tutorial...

Comment: That is the question, how can I work with the pixels?

Comment: Have you done any reading on working with pointers in C?  If you have no experience with that, unfortunately it's something that's completely outside the scope of a SO question.

Comment: @R3dLinE something like this http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/Pixel_Access . I'm not sure it handles all possible pixel formats but basic idea remains the same.

Comment: You probably want to convert the surface to a specific format first, so you don't have to support all of them.